# Unable to read deeplink URL in AppDelegate method (swift 4, iOS 13)

Tags: ios, swift, deeplink

I'm trying deeplink to open particular page in app on click of shared link from other app/from safari, URL opens the app but unable to take application on particular page i,e, unable to read link (custom URL). This is my custom URL :- WOT://tradeDetail
If anyone knows where i'm going wrong, please help

here is screenshot and code

[image]

```
var window: UIWindow?
var scheme = "WOT"

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

    GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey(WOT.googlePlaceAPIKey)

    if let url = launchOptions?[.url] as? URL {
        return handle(url: url)
    }
    return true
}

func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    return handle(url: url)
}

func handle(url: URL) -> Bool {
    switch url.absoluteString {
    case "\(scheme)://tradeDetail" : do {
        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: .main)
        let detailView = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SearchedPlaceDetailVC") as? SearchedPlaceDetailVC
        window?.rootViewController = detailView
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    default: return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: #Abhishek Suryawanshi did you solve this problem? I am getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call below function to navigate particular page

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity:
        NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {

        let myUrl: String? = userActivity.webpageURL?.absoluteString

        if myUrl?.range(of: "tradeDetail") != nil {

            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)

            let yourViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: “YourViewController”) as? YourViewController

            self.window?.rootViewController = yourViewController
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        }

        return true
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the help.
I tried you piece of code but things are still same. It is not redirecting to that particular page.

Comment: Are you getting myUrl in log?

Comment: No. Even if I print URL in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, it is showing blank.

Comment: You have to add domains in signing and capabilities. And url must be start with https.